# JQuery fadeOut image to fadeIn new image

Tags: jquery

Currently just starting looking into JQuery and i'm currently playing around with some of the functions fadeIn(), fadeOut(), toggle().

I've created a div which holds multiple images and i've created a simple image fadeOut to new image fadeIn by following Snooks tutorial using JQuery.

My problem is, my first image fades completely out to a white screen before the new image fades in and the outcome I wanted to achieve is the first image fades out whilst the second image fades in so it looks like a smoother transition.

I've looked through JQuery docs and I thought the answer to my problem was maybe by setting Queue(false) but this does not seem to work.

I've created a fiddle (minus the pictures) I've used and would appreciate if someone could help me.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fadein">
  <img width="800" height="420" src="images/wallpaper_2.jpg" />
  <img width="800" height="420" src="images/bognor2.jpg" />
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23p4c8v0/)

Thanks in advance and feel free to ask further questions if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/23p4c8v0/2/

To achieve that you need to define this css:

```
.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

See it working:

```js
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function() {
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000).delay(7000)
    .next('img').fadeIn(1000)
    .end().appendTo('.fadein');
}, 7000);
```

```css
.fadein {
  width: 800px;
  height: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.fadein img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadein">
  <img width="800" height="420" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Image+1" />
  <img width="800" height="420" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/dbdbdb/000cb3&text=Image+2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks a lot.